# add double quotes at the start and end of each string of column pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

hello guyes  im using pyspark 2.3

i have a dataframe with string column named "code_lei"
i want to add double quotes at the start and end of each string in the column without deleting or changing the blanck space between the strings of the column

```
input dataframe : 
+----+--------------+------+------------+-------+--------------------+
|vide|       integer|double|xx_dt_arrete|vide_de|            code_lei|
+----+--------------+------+------------+-------+--------------------+
|null|10000000000000|   1.1|  2021-06-30|   null|  code_lei et chorba|
|null|10000000000000|   1.1|  2021-06-30|   null|                null|
|null|10000000000000|   1.1|  2021-06-30|   null| code_lei et chorba |
|null|10000000000000|   1.1|  2021-06-30|   null|     code_lei ee    |
|null|             2|   2.2|        null|   null|            code_lei|
|null|             2|   2.2|        null|   null|            code_lei|
|null|             2|   2.2|        null|   null|            code_lei|
|null|             2|   2.2|        null|   null|            code_lei|
+----+--------------+------+------------+-------+--------------------+
```

```
Output Datafame : 
+----+--------------+------+------------+-------+--------------------+
|vide|       integer|double|xx_dt_arrete|vide_de|            code_lei|
+----+--------------+------+------------+-------+--------------------+
|null|10000000000000|   1.1|  2021-06-30|   null|  "code_lei" "et" "chorba"|
|null|10000000000000|   1.1|  2021-06-30|   null|                null|
|null|10000000000000|   1.1|  2021-06-30|   null| "code_lei" "et" "chorba" |
|null|10000000000000|   1.1|  2021-06-30|   null|     "code_lei" "ee"    |
|null|             2|   2.2|        null|   null|            "code_lei"|
|null|             2|   2.2|        null|   null|            "code_lei"|
|null|             2|   2.2|        null|   null|            "code_lei"|
|null|             2|   2.2|        null|   null|            "code_lei"|
+----+--------------+------+------------+-------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe like this

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("hello there",),
    ("hello world",),
], ['text'])

+-----------+
|       text|
+-----------+
|hello there|
|hello world|
+-----------+
```

You can then apply a chain of transformation like this

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('splitted', F.split('text', ' '))
    .withColumn('joined', F.array_join(F.col('splitted'), '" "'))
    .withColumn('wrapped', F.concat(F.lit('"'), F.col('joined'), F.lit('"')))
    .show()
)

+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|       text|      splitted|       joined|        wrapped|
+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|hello there|[hello, there]|hello" "there|"hello" "there"|
|hello world|[hello, world]|hello" "world|"hello" "world"|
+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Or you can add them all together like this

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('wrapped', F.concat(F.lit('"'), F.array_join(F.split('text', ' '), '" "'), F.lit('"')))
    .show()
)
+-----------+---------------+
|       text|        wrapped|
+-----------+---------------+
|hello there|"hello" "there"|
|hello world|"hello" "world"|
+-----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lit  and concat functions for this purpose.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn("code_lei",F.concat(F.lit('"'),F.col('code_lei'),F.lit('"'))).show()
```

Comment: This is not the requirement , I did this already

Comment: Then show what you did

Comment: I thought you wanted to add double quotes at the beginning and end, thats the way to do it. Can you further elaborate please ?